# Will this hardware handle Netflix View Instantly?

Tags: nvidia-ion, netflix, intel-atom

I know Intel Atom cpus are limited in their performance.  This model seems to have a Nvidia 9400 graphics card.  It supposedly plays 1080p video and blueray quite nicely.  Will this be able to stream Netflix View Instantly?

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883103228

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netflix Instant Watch runs great on my [EEEPc 900HA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GIPSAM) which has less horsepower than the machine you linked. You should be fine.

Comment: thanks, for 200 bucks, I think I may grab one of these.  Looks like a potential hackintosh perhaps as well.  Looking forward to playing with this.

Comment: What OS do you run on your Asus?

Comment: I've had XP, Windows 7 (currently) and Ubuntu on this machine at one point or anothber. Only hardware change I've made is a 2GB RAM upgrade for about 15 bucks.

Comment: For $135, you can buy a Wii, and it comes with Mario Kart.  And it supports Netflix Instant. Although not in HD.  Also, you could get an XBox 360 for $199, which I believe does support Netflix Live in HD. These options aren't the same as a PC, but are quite a bit friendlier when used on your TV.

Comment: Yes, I know people who use these (older models) for that very purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In testing, it appears to have plenty of horsepower with the ION in it. But, unfortunately, the review of this I saw didn't look specifically at Netflix View Instantly.

I really don't see why this one won't work, but if you are really concerned, I would wait for some reviews of it to come out that specifically address the View Instantly feature.

Comment: In the few reviews I have looked at, they seem to address Hulu and youtube.  It seems it will run it ok in a browser but struggle more full-screen.  Will streaming netflix be the same as hulu?  Does hulu use flash?  I know Netflix uses Silverlight?  Anyone give any insight who owns an Intel Atom netbook and how it handles netflix?